# Import multiple XML files to Excel

Tags: xml, excel, import

I've got around 200 XML files with the same format. They all look like this:

```
<Application>
    <IntakeSection0 Title="">
        <Item01 Text="Question1" Value="Answer1" Comment=""/>
        <Item02 Text="Question2" Value="Answer2" Comment=""/>
    </IntakeSection0>
    <IntakeSection1 Title="title1">
        <Item11 Text="Question3" Value="Answer3" Comment=""/>
        <Item12 Text="Question4" Value="Answer4" Comment=""/>
        <Item13 Text="Question5" Value="Answer5" Comment=""/>
        <Item14 Text="Question6" Value="Answer6" Comment=""/>
    </IntakeSection1>
    <IntakeSection2 Title="title2">
        <Item21 Text="Question7" Value="Answer7" Comment=""/>
        <Item22 Text="Question8" Value="Answer8" Comment=""/>
        <Item23 Text="Question9" Value="Answer9" Comment=""/>
    </IntakeSection2>
</Application>
```

The whole XML exists of 65 Questions, but you get the idea after 9 ;)

I would like to import all of these 200 XML's at once.
The problem is however that I only need the Values (Answer6 for example) from the XML.

My Excelsheet needs to look like this:

(for XML file 1) Answer1       Answer2       Answer3       Answer4

(for XML file 2) Answer1       Answer2       Answer3       Answer4

(for XML file 3) Answer1       Answer2       Answer3       Answer4

(for XML file 4) Answer1       Answer2       Answer3       Answer4

I already searched a lot and came with some ideas, first of all i used XML-Source on the developers tab of Excel, here i could create an XML-source file. I just dragged and dropped the Values where i wanted them. This works perfectly for one XML. But its not possible to import 200 at the same time.

Maybe there is somebody that knows what to do.

Thanks in advance,

MisterQ

Answer (score -2):

If you've found a way to import one file I think that the shortest way for you is to consider that XML files are just a form of text files so you can easily merge them togheter.

For example you could put all your XML files into a folder and, in the same folder, save the following instructions as "OneXML.bat"

```
@echo off
copy *.xml TheOne.xml
```

(Under Windows) if you double click on "OneXML.bat" this will generate a single XML file that you can import in the same way you import a single file.
Tell us if this is ok for you, otherways we'll look for something more sophisticated.

Comment: XML files are not *just a form of text files*. They have a declaration at the top that indicates they are XML, declares namespaces, and provides encoding information and that is allowed only once per file. In addition, valid XML has a single root node. Concatenating the files together as you've demonstrated would make the entire group of files invalid.

Comment: OK, so what is your best solution to import several XML files into Excel? Consider that the user seems to do not have a valid XSD file or inline schema. Of course XML without any form of schema, BAT scripts and Excel are not a good ingredients for a state of the art solutions but it may be useful for a novice user that want to get the solution, and not to spend time becaming an XML expert.

Answer (score -2):

I found this old question while searching to import a bunch of InfoPath generated XML files into Excel (one file per survey response).  I ended up with this indirect approach using powershell to first make a single CSV which made importing the data to Excel painless:

```
$files=Get-ChildItem "x:\folder with xml files\*" -Include *.xml
$outFile="x:\folder with xml files\Results.csv"
Remove-Item $outFile -ErrorAction Ignore
$xml = New-Object -TypeName -XML
foreach ($file in files){
  $xml.Load($file)
  Write-Host "Adding $file"
  $xml.myfields | Select-Object -Property Question1, Quesiton2, Question3 |Export-CSV $outFile -NoTypeInformation -Deliminter "|" -Append -encoding UTF8
}
```

This spits out a CSV file (I used | as a delimiter because my responses contained commas) that I was able to quickly import into Excel.